# ArcGIS: Add XY Data isn't plotting in the correct location.

Tags: arcgis-desktop, excel

I've done this correctly so many times, I don't understand what's wrong.

- The x and y columns I'm plotting are in decimal degrees.
- Latitude is X and Longitude is Y.
- I am plotting to Nad 1983 datum, which is consistent to my data frame and all my other layers. The points I'm plotting were taken in Nad 1983 datum.

They plot, but in the wrong location. What other things could be wrong?

Comment: could you have X,Y reversed?

Comment: Whelp... switching x to y worked... Thank you for your outside clarity

Comment: don't forget the negative in front of your longitude values!

Answer (score 4):

Your Latitude should be on the Y axis. Longitude on the X axis. You have them backwards.